# Check for changes in a text column

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, t-sql, trigger

Using SQL Server 2012, how can I check for changes in a text column?

I know the text datatype has been deprecated, and get the ever helpful message

> Cannot use text, ntext, or image columns in the 'inserted' and 'deleted' tables.

when trying to reference the existing text column in a trigger, so things like joining inserted & deleted tables on the column does not work.  UPDATE() *would* work, except it is always true (I am guessing the front end just pushes whatever data is in the form field regardless if it changed or not).

Any suggestions on how I can check for changes on the column?

Comment: What kind of data are you storing in this column?

Comment: Text   :-)    Free-form user notes.

Comment: You are using the wrong data type.  Try varchar(max).

Comment: I am not using the wrong data type, the vendor is; unfortunately I have no control over it.

Comment: Have you looked into Change Data Capture? This page, [Track Data Changes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb933994.aspx#Anchor_2) does not indicate that the `TEXT` datatype would be a problem. Or, perhaps create an Indexed View that selects the PK column(s) and then `CONVERT(VARCHAR(MAX), tbl.UserNotes)`, and then create an `AFTER UPDATE` Trigger on the Indexed View?

Comment: @Bill Wallace, I'd recommend you to specify what sql server version you are using so we can assist you better.

Comment: How newb of me :-/  SqlServer 2012

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you implement an INSTEAD OF UPDATE trigger? - a quick test on my local instances indicates you can reference the inserted and deleted tables.  Naturally, you still have to apply the real update.

here was my quick test

```
create table TextDataTypeTest (Col1 text)
insert into dbo.textdatatypetest (col1) values('test')
----------------
create TRIGGER dbo.TextDataTypeTest_Trigger
   ON  dbo.TextDataTypeTest 
   instead of UPDATE
AS 
BEGIN

select col1 into #Before from deleted
select col1 into #After from inserted

select * from #Before

select * from #After
update a 
set a.col1=b.col1 
from dbo.textdatatypetest a join
inserted b on 1=1

END
GO


update dbo.textdatatypetest set col1='oneforalx'
```

Comment: That's what I'm leaning towards, but I still cannot access the text data-type columns in the i & d tables.  I am thinking with an INSTEAD OF UPDATE trigger I can pull the original value, proceed with the update, pull the new value, and then do the compare.  This is the approach I will try next.

Comment: Hmm, perhaps i'm missing something, but i didn't have any problems accessing the text column from the i & d tables.  I updated my answer with my very quick prototype, but again, maybe i'm missing something

Comment: I will check this later, but I am WAGing that you a using an older version of SqlServer from before depreciation of the text datatype.

Comment: My testing was done on sql 2014 sp2

Comment: Y'all right, text columns can be accessed in INSTEAD OF triggers.  https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175196(v=sql.105).aspx

Answer (score 0):

Just as @Scott Hodgin mentioned, you can actually use INSTEAD OF trigger to work around your requirement.

Here is a more detailed solution template for your reference (details are explained in the comments)

```
use tempdb
go
-- create a sample table
if object_id('dbo.t', 'U') is not null
    drop table dbo.t;

-- we assume this table has a PK, so we can utilize this PK column(s) in the trigger
create table dbo.t (id int identity primary key, a text, b int); 
go

-- insert initial record
insert into dbo.t (a, b) values ('hello world', 10);
go

if object_id('dbo.upd_trg', 'TR') is not null
    drop trigger upd_trg;
go
create trigger upd_trg on dbo.t
instead of update
as
begin
  set nocount on;
  declare @d table (id int primary key, a varchar(max), b int); -- store deleted table, change [a] column from text data type to varchar(max)
  declare @i table (id int primary key, a varchar(max), b int); -- store inserted table, 

  insert into @d (id, a, b) select id, a, b from deleted;
  insert into @i (id, a, b) select id, a, b from inserted;

  if exists (select * from @i i inner join @d d on i.id = d.id and i.a <> d.a)
  begin
      -- you can put your own business logic here, such as log the before/after update into a separate table
      print 'column [a] changed'; 
  end
  update t set t.a = i.a, t.b =i.b  -- now cntinue to do the update
  from dbo.t t
  inner join @i i
  on i.id = t.id 

end
go

-- an example here
-- when we update column [a] with different value, a message "column [a] changed" will be printed out
update dbo.t set a='good morning', b = b+b
from dbo.t
where id = 1;

-- check it, [a] should be 'good morning' instead of the original 'hello world', and [b]=20 instead of original 10
select * from dbo.t where id =1;

-- when we do NOT update column [a] but other columns like [b], NO message will be printed out
update dbo.t set  b = b+b
from dbo.t
where id = 1;

-- check it, [a] should be still 'good morning', while [b] = 40 instead of 20 
select * from dbo.t where id =1;
```

This is tested in SQL Server 2012 version 11.0.5623.0 (x64)